# Keeping specified variables in ProGuard

Tags: java, obfuscation, proguard

I have certain variable names that need to be protected from obfuscation as they are keywords in a separate library I call.

Right now I've used -keepclassmembers, like so:

```
    -keepclassmembers class package.classname{
       public final int id;
       public long runtime;
    }
```

I used -keepclassmembers for a different class where I was able to protect a String from obfuscation.
I'm not sure if the problem is because I'm trying to protect primitives... any help regarding this will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks plausible. If the fields exist, you should find them listed in bin/proguard/seeds.text. If you also want to preserve the class, you should use `-keep` instead of just `-keepclassmembers`.